# Finding if an element is childless

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains all elements on the page. How would I test if an element is childless while looping through the array? I would prefer to stay with standard javascript. Here is pseudocode that explains it:

```
for each element in elementlist:
    if element is childless:
        do something
    else:
        do something different
```

Comment: What do you mean by `childless`? Do you consider text nodes as child elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hasChildNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.hasChildNodes) method which returns a boolean

```
element.hasChildNodes();
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure JS, you would test if elem.firstChild is null, with jQuery you could test with elem.children().length > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the number of child nodes with `element.childNodes.length`. If it's equal to `0`, the node is childless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution and a demo.  This includes elements with children that are text nodes.

```
var arr = [document.getElementById("a1"),
           document.getElementById("a2"),
           document.getElementById("a3"),
           document.getElementById("a4")];

var isChildless = function(ele){
    return ele.childNodes.length <= 0;
}

for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
    console.log(isChildless(arr[x]));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTbuB/1/

Answer (score 0):

if the array is long try to use

```
 var z=arr.length;
 for (var x = 0; x < z ; x += 1){
 console.log(isChildless(arr[x]));
```

it will count the length once. In previous example it counts arr.length in every loop.